# Ncn-civi-zoom or ZoomZoom?

Tags: civirules, integration, zoom

Exploring a possibility of Zoom.us integration. There are quite a lot of search results to read, however in 2023, which of the extensions has, in your opinion, smoother integration experience? It looks like both rely on CiviRules but would one of them work without it? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a little table comparing CiviZoom Alternative and ZoomZoom.  Maybe it will help someone else.

[image: comparison table]

Answer (score 1):

Can't say what is 'best', but [CiviZoom Alternative](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/ncn-civi-zoom) works.  The older JWT authentication was retired by Zoom in favour of OAuth.  You do need CiviRules but it is simple to set up.

Comment: Thank you as always! A bit pity CiviRules is inevitable though.